# reading bit mask and bits in the following example

Tags: objective-c, mask, bit

Can someone explain how to read these two bit masks?

```
uint32_t = 0x1 << 0;
uint32_t = 0x1 << 1;
```

Basically, how would you translate this to a person that can't read code? Which one is smaller than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 0x1 is just the hex value of 1, which in binary is represented as ~001. When you apply a 0 bit shift to 0x1, the value is unchanged because you haven't actually shifted anything. When you shift 1, you're looking at a representation of ~010 which in good ol' numerics is a 2 because you have a 1 in the twos column and zeros everywhere else.

Therefore, `uint32_t i = 0x1 << 0;` has a lesser value than `uint32_t j = 0x1 << 1;`.

```
uint32_t i = 0x1 << 0;
uint32_t j = 0x1 << 1;

NSLog(@"%u",i);   // outputs 1
NSLog(@"%u",j);   // outputs 2
```